# set CookieManager every where java?

Tags: java, cookies

Should i set

```
CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);
```

In every class file where it connects to the internet and uses cookies or is it suffecient to set it only one place ?

I'm planning to use the cookies recieved during login in any other new connections made from other threads and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Read it from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html#setDefault%28java.net.CookieHandler%29). This is system-wide.